# php + mysql updating some records and deleting others

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have an html form with a `<select>` for the user and the checkboxes for user roles. The values get stored into the following mysql table:

```
UserId   | RoleId |
1        | 1      |
1        | 3      |
1        | 4      |
2        | 2      |
...
```

Suppose I need to edit the roles for `UserId = 1`, I need only `RoleId = 1 and 3`. Then PHP return the originally stored values of RoleIds 1, 3, 4 into the form's checkboxes. Then I uncheck the checkbox for `RoleId = 4` and hit save.

What mysql code should I use to handle this update?

Comment: You'll need to write a code that handles the save and checks which checkboxes are checked. And we are not going to write it for you.

Comment: i don't think it's that easy as you mention. problem is that if there are some role ids that's not needed, i'll need to delete them. so it's not only checking the inputs and handling saving, it's also deleting stuff. and that's where i'm stuck at...

Comment: Yeah but you'll have to do a lot of research on google or even here on Stack Overflow. Asking for a direct code source is not ok.

Comment: didn't really get your point about research (sensed a bit of mocking here :) ). i wasn't asking for the whole code, i just need the mysql part. php part isn't a problem.

Comment: and actually, there're plenty of answers here where people give out code, and it's not a big problem. if you don't wanna help, it's no problem, just pass by, and you don't really need to write something like you're not going to write it for me.